How can I add many-to-many relationships between tables from different databases?
I'm writing a pet project online store on golang. I split the monolithic architecture into microservice architecture and use a separate postgres DB for each microservice.
I have two microservices: products-microservice and categories-microservice
The tables for them look like this:
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "uuid-ossp";

create table if not exists products
(
    id UUID PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(),
    name TEXT NOT NULL,
    description TEXT NOT NULL,
    price NUMERIC NOT NULL,
    created_at TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
    updated_at TIMESTAMP
);

Categories Table:
create table categories
(
    id serial primary key,
    name text not null,
    slug text not null,
    created_at timestamp not null default now(),
    updated_at timestamp
);

How can I add a category field to the product table if they are in different databases? Is there such a possibility, or do these tables have to be in the same database?

Just add a column, that’s it. You can add whatever you want, but there will be no actual relation between them since they’re in separate databases and microservices. They should not have anything to do with each other directly. Do you really want to separate products and categories?

@SamiKuhmonen Which is considered the better option? Add just category_id or merge all related tables into one database?

Not possible and it will destroy performance: You need many database connections, query planner can't do a good job to pick the best query plan, etc. etc. If there is a relation between the tables, put the tables in the same database. Otherwise there is no relation and you could drop one database without any problems for the rest of your system.

I'm not sure, but I think I would have tried separating functional areas by schema before going a step up to the database level.
If there are relationships between tables, that kind of implies they are part of the same database.
